# Can I get user history with Analytics API?

Tags: analytics-api

Can I do so? 
that I will send user id from cookies to Google Analytics API and I will get all my site pages which was visited by user?

I do not found any example of this.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit (i.e., you want to track a user ID from page-to-page using Google Analytics)?

Comment: I want to get user browse history from Google analytic, when I send an ID to Analytic from Google cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics does not generally allow tracking of individual users.   It views it as a privacy violation.   Google Analytics only supplies reports that aggregate user data.

See [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095225/tracking-individual-users-with-google-analytics-custom-variables) about using custom variables with your user id of the user in it.  That is a solution that is now allowed (as long as Google can't associate the user id with names, addresses, or emails).